# C# Dictionary ContainsKey Vs Keys.Any()

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Here is my situation:

I am using dictionary object to store some keys, and then based on key exists in the object, code is performing some action.

Till now I was using - LINQ - `Any()` `dictionaryObject.Any(x => x.Key.Equals("SomeParameter"))`. This was working will and satisfying all scenarios till my dictionary object suddenly got 200,000 keys.

It started impacting on performance, and so does rest of process.

Then I realize, there is a dictionary method `ContainsKey("SomeParameter")`, and after using this, performance really improved.

Now I am more interested to see what `ContainsKey` does different than LINQ `Any` as I underlined code uses `for` & `foreach` respectively, which means it loops thru the list.

Comment: `ContainsKey` will use the key's hash to see if the dictionary contains it.  This is O(1).  `Any()` does not use dictionary lookup, and is O(n).

Comment: You can use the [.NET framework reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) when you are curious about the internals of a framework method, or read the documentation for a particular framework class at the [.NET API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netframework-4.7.2) which explains why `Dictionary` lookup [is fast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks). You can also see how `Any` is implemented and what special cases it handles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a code for ContainsKey method

```
  private int FindEntry(TKey key)
    {
      if ((object) key == null)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
      if (this.buckets != null)
      {
        int num = this.comparer.GetHashCode(key) & int.MaxValue;
        for (int index = this.buckets[num % this.buckets.Length]; index >= 0; index = this.entries[index].next)
        {
          if (this.entries[index].hashCode == num && this.comparer.Equals(this.entries[index].key, key))
            return index;
        }
      }
      return -1;
    }
```

As you might see, once you have a key,

- you get hash code for it
- access bucket to get index
- access data with that index

It's O(1) operations, while `Any` is a part of `IEnumerable`, and performs simple iteration over a sequence of elements, until condition is met, hence O(n) - much less scallable. And that's what you observe - with amount of data that grows, performance becomes worse for `Any`.

See declaration of `Dictionary` from System.Collections.Generic, mscorlib

```
   public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
                    ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, 
                    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>,  //this one "brings" Any
                    IEnumerable, 
                    IDictionary, 
                    ICollection, 
                    IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
                    IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, 
                    ISerializable, 
                    IDeserializationCallback
```

Comment: Nice explanation!

In case someone waned to see source from where the code snip was posted... https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,297